# How to return a grid as a function?

Tags: python

So i have an assignment where i have to use a test code to check if my code is working, what im trying to do is define a grid as a function and return it so that the test code can use it.

The test code:

```
def run_test (test):
    if test == 0:
        grid = [] 
        print(grid)   
        util.create_grid (grid)
        # import from a different file
        print (len (grid))
        print (len (grid[0]))
        print (len (grid[1]))
        print (len (grid[2]))
        print (len (grid[3]))
        print (grid[0][0])
        print (grid[1][2])
        print (grid[2][1])
        print (grid[3][3])
```

My code(from a different file):

```
def create_grid(grid):
  
  grid = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
  
  return grid
```

The error im getting:
print (len (grid[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Edit the question to explain what happens. If there is an error message show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Does `create_grid` always ignore its argument?

Comment: (1) In the future you should include the full traceback of an error and format it properly. (2) But in this case the mistake is simple: The test function expects that you modify the list object given as parameter to your function ("extend" method can help here) while you create and return a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are ignoring the return value of `create_grid`:

```
grid = util.create_grid(grid)
```

Given that you never use `grid` before reassigning it, it would be simpler to pass any object as the argument (the function ignores it anyway):

```
if test == 0:
    grid = util.create_grid([])
```

Comment: I guess the poster isn't allowed to modify the test function.

Comment: As the answer was accepted my guess was obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If all files are under your control and you can modify them , I see two problems:

1. The parameter `grid` in this method is never used. It should be removed

   ```
   def create_grid(grid):  
       grid = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
       return grid
   ```
2. The return value is never used. It should be

   ```
    grid = util.create_grid()
   ```

If you can't modify `test_run()`, because that's out of control, you need to find a way to modify the array without an assignment.

In that case, start with

```
grid.clear()
```

to ensure the array will be empty. After that add values using

```
grid.append()
```

or

```
grif.extend()
```

Comment: I guess the poster isn't allowed to modify the test function.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: indeed, that could be the case. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @MichaelButscher: we'll see when OP comes back and changes his opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In your `create_grid()` function, `grid` variable is only in the scope of the function, so it will edit your argument only in your function.

Example:

```py
>>> grid = []
>>> def create_grid(grid):
...     grid = [1, 2, 3]
...
>>> create_grid(grid)
>>> print(grid)
[]
```

Here you can see that your `grid` variable didn't change.

What you should do is to return your grid after your changed it (you already did that) and define your `grid` variable in your `run_test()` function to the return value of the function like that:

```py
>>> grid = []
>>> def create_grid(grid):
...     grid = [1, 2, 3]
...     return grid
...
>>> grid = create_grid(grid)
>>> print(grid)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here your `grid` variable did change.

Note that here you do not need to pass your grid as argument as you redefine it in your function anyway.

So your code should looks like that:

```py
def create_grid():
  grid = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
  return grid
```

```py
grid = util.create_grid()
```

If your want to learn more about scopes, please refer to [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

Comment: I guess the poster isn't allowed to modify the test function.